# Weird segmentation fault when overloading the new operator

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, new-operator

I'm trying to create a memory pool and overload the new operator, so I malloc'ated a bunch of addresses at the beginning of my program

The allocation in class MemPool:

```
 void MemPool::initialize(int size) {

    charArray = (char*)malloc(size);
    currentAddress = charArray;
    lastAddress = charArray + size;
 }
```

This is my Main.cpp:

```
MemoryManager mm;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Object* obj1 = new Object();
}
```

Operators.cpp

```
extern MemoryManager mm;

void* operator new(size_t size) {
    void* chunk = mm.getAChunk(size);
return chunk;
}
```

And here is my getAChunk method:

```
void* MemoryManager::getAChunk(int size) {
    char* chunkToReturn = nullptr;

    int power = ceil(log2(size));
    int storageSpace = pow(2,power);

    Block* poppedBlock = freeList[power].popFirstBlock();

    if (poppedBlock==nullptr) {
        int sizer = mPool->getLastAddress() - mPool->getCurrentAddress();
        if ( sizer > storageSpace+sizeof(Block) ) {

            char* currAddress = mPool->getCurrentAddress();
            Block* block = (Block*)currAddress;
            block->setPower(power);
            block->setNextBlock(nullptr);

            currAddress += sizeof(Block);
            chunkToReturn = currAddress;

            mPool->incrementCurrentAddress(storageSpace+sizeof(Block));

        } else {
            cout << "- Could not allocate space -" << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "Using existing block " << endl;

        char* addrToReturn = (char*) poppedBlock;
        addrToReturn += sizeof(Block);
        chunkToReturn = addrToReturn;
    }

    return chunkToReturn;
}
```

The code above works, and when I try to create a new Object which is larger than my memory pool, it will print 'could not allocate space' as intended.
But once I add a number to the constructor of Object:

```
Object* obj1 = new Object(5);
```

Then I will get a segmentation fault when trying to create an Object which is larger than my memory pool.
The same occurs when instead of a new Object I create:

```
double* d1 = new double;    // does not cause segmentation fault.
double* d1 = new double();  // causes a segmentation fault.
```

My Object class is just a simple class:

```
class Object {
 int num;
 int sum;
 double sam;  

 public:
    Object() {}
    Object(int num) { sum = num; }
    void print() { cout << " This is an object " << endl;}
};
```

/////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT:

To check where the segfault occurs I added this cout's:

```
void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
   void* chunk = mm.getAChunk(size);
   if (chunk == nullptr) {
     cout << "1" << endl;
     return chunk;
   }
   cout << "2" << endl;
   return chunk;
 }
```

I've created the pool small enough so that getAChunk will return a nullptr.
When I create a double without parenthesis it will print "1" and return without any problem, but after I add the parenthesis it will print "1" and cause a segmentation fault in the return statement.
I assume the segfault occurs at the return statement since after

```
double* d1 = new double(4);
```

I tried a simple print which does not print

If it matters, my code runs on c9.io

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code to find out where the segfault occurs?

Comment: The difference is that in cases your program  segfaults you actually are using the memory. With the parenthesis the double will be zero initialized and with constructor sum will be set to a num. So I assume something is wrong with pointer you return. Have you tried to use the memory, e.g, `double* d1 = new double; *d1 = 1.0;`? Does it work?

Comment: What @AriHietanen says and also alignment, you increment the returning pointer by `sizeof(Block)`  this may make the returned pointer not correctly aligned for the final data type.

Comment: OT: Please note that calling a constructor parameter exactly the same as a class member may be confusing: https://ideone.com/Ee4UX1

Comment: Can you give us enough code to replicate the problem ourselves? Preferably with a `main` function so we can compile it, run it, and see the error.

Comment: Which compiler are you using and on which architecture?

Comment: I've added more information to the post.
@AriHietanen, I've tried using the memory and it works